# Overlay a smaller image over larger image using WriteableBitmapEx Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, blit, writeablebitmapex

In my hidden object  game, I want to mark the object with a circle image when found with the following code where AnsX1, AnsX2, AnsY1, an AnsY2 is the pixel coordinates of the object location. The circle image should be resized according to the object size marked by the pixel coordinates

```
        imgCat.Source = writeableBmp;

        WriteableBitmap wbCircle = new WriteableBitmap(AnsX2 - AnsX1, AnsY2 - AnsY1);
        wbCircle = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromContent("Images/circle.png");

        //Just to make sure the boundary is correct so I draw the green rec around the object
        writeableBmp.DrawRectangle(AnsX1, AnsY1, AnsX2, AnsY2, Colors.Green);

        Rect sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
        Rect destRect = new Rect(AnsX1, AnsY1, wbCircle.PixelWidth, wbCircle.PixelHeight);

        writeableBmp.Blit(destRect, wbCircle, sourceRect);
        writeableBmp.Invalidate();
```

My problem is instead of having one large circle I have several smaller circles filling the rectangle area at the top (see image):

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
Based on @Rene response I've changed the code to

```
        imgCat.Source = writeableBmp;

        //Just to make sure the boundary is correct so I draw the green rec around the object
        writeableBmp.DrawRectangle(AnsX1, AnsY1, AnsX2, AnsY2, Colors.Green);
        WriteableBitmap wbCircle = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromContent("Images/circle.png");
        wbCircle = wbCircle.Resize(AnsX2 - AnsX1, AnsY2 - AnsY1, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

        Rect sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
        Rect destRect = new Rect(AnsX1, AnsY1, AnsX2 - AnsX1, AnsY2 - AnsY1);

        writeableBmp.Blit(destRect, wbCircle, sourceRect);
        writeableBmp.Invalidate();
```

Here's the result

[image]

I will use a larger and better quality circle.png if I manage to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think the circle.png is too small. The Blit method does not scale up. You would need to scale it up first using the Scale function like so:

```
wbCircle = wbCircle.Resize(AnsX2 - AnsX1, AnsY2 - AnsY1, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```

And second the sourceRect uses the size of the whole / destination bitmap and not that of the wbCircle / source bitmap. Should be:

```
sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, wbCircle.PixelWidth, wbCircle.PixelHeight);
```

The scaling could lead to some scaling artifacts if circle is too small and the up scaling is too high. If you really only need a simple colored circle, you can also use the DrawCircle method instead:

```
writeableBmp.DrawCircle(AnsX1, AnsY1, AnsX2, AnsY2, Colors.Green);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The circle becomes larger after a resize but it still does not fill the whole rectangle. I edited my question

Comment: Weird. Could you upload a sample project somewhere. This would speed this process up a lot. But why are you not simply using DrawCircle?

Comment: OK will upload a sample project. I tried DrawCircle but the circle lines seem a little jagged (I draw five circles of different sizes to produce thicker brush). Anyway, I think using image to mark the location will look nicer as the image I intend to use is not a simple circle. :)

Comment: OK. the sourceRect uses the size of the whole / destination bitmap and not that of the wbCircle / source bitmap. I edited my reply above.